# Having a GET request hyperlink in PHP page that itself is called upon following another similar hyperlink

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, get, xampp

I have 3 PHP pages:

1. `My_posts.php`
2. `ReaderBlog.php`
3. `index.php`

`index.php` is a default home page. All files are under the same folder called 'Better_blog' under `htdocs` in the XAMPP server.

Now in `my_posts.php`, I have a hyperlink like:

```
<a href="ReaderBlog.php?id=4">Goto Reader </a>
```

This triggers a GET request with parameter in URL to `ReaderBlog.php, in which it's able to decipher the GET request.

Now in `ReaderBlog.php` I have another GET request hyperlink to `index.php` like:

```
<a href="index.php">Click here to go to index page</a>
```

This link when clicked generates a URL like:

```
http://localhost/Better_blog/ReaderBlog.php/index.php
```

Which is incorrect behavior.

Instead, I expect:

```
http://localhost/Better_blog/index.php
```

Why is `index.php` getting appended to `ReaderBlog.php`?

Comment: To set `GET` variables in the URL, use the following  format: `http://example.com/mypage.php?foo=something&bar=somethingelse` which sets the `foo` and `bar` variables in the `$_GET` array

Comment: Are you using the tag `<base>` inside your `<head>` in your files?

Answer (score 3):

Change the link to:

```
 <a href="ReaderBlog.php?id=4">Goto Reader </a>
```

Note the `?` instead of `/`

Comment: sorry, above was a typo.. I have it the same way with '?' not '/' in my program.. I corrected it.. As said I am able to read the passed GET parameter.. but any hyperlink fired from that page is leading to a malformed URL like `http://localhost/Better_blog/ReaderBlog.php/index.php` instead of `http://localhost/Better_blog/index.php`..  should I hard code the URL?

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the current links of `index.php` and `ReaderBlog.php`? You shouldn't hard code it. It's not good to maintenance. Example, every time you change the host name you will need to change all links.